# How to manage an array brought from a query into a php form select

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, drop-down-menu

I'm triying to assemble a Select intput for a form in HTML/PHP, from JavaScript, as follows:

```
  function cerrando(){
    $(".creaDetFact").empty();
    $(".bvp").empty();
    var rfFac = $("#rfFac").val();
    var vTDF = "Pago de Factura";
    var datos = new FormData();
    datos.append("rdffac",rfFac);
    document.getElementById("TDF").innerHTML = vTDF;
    $(".creaDetFact").append(
      '<form role="form" method="post" autocomplete="off">'+
        '<div class="form-group">'+
          '<div class="col-xs-6" style="padding-right: 0px;">'+
            '<div class="input-group">'+
              '<select class="form-control input-lg" type="number" name="creaCate" id="creaCate" required>'+
                '<option value="">Seleccione Categoría</option>'+
                '<?php'+
                  $.ajax({
                    url: "ajax/ventas.ajax.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: datos,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (dataset){

/* This above procedure brings back an array of n rows */

                      foreach(dataset){
                        echo '<option value=' + dataset["mp_pago"] + '>' + dataset["mp_descripcion"] + '</option>'+
                      }

/* why is the parser telling me that this instruction is wrong */
                      
                    }
                  }) +
                '?>'+
              '</select>'+
            '</div>'+
          '</div>'+
          '<div class="col-xs-6" style="padding-left: 0px;">'+
            '<div class="input-group">'+
              '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="rfTsc" name="rfTsc" required>'+
              '<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>'+
            '</div>'+
          '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<button type="button" style="margin-right: 40px" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Guardar</button>'+
      '</form>'
    );
```

the parser of VSC is telling me that I have an error at the foreach and I can't get it

As I've said, I'm trying to assemble a select input for a HTML/PHP form, from Javascript, with the dataset coming from a query to the database.

The query brings back n rows (5, 4, 3, depending on the query) and those rows are parameters for a Select input in the intended form

Comment: are you trying to append php script in your javascript, this is not possible. you can just echo javascript from php and browser will execute it.

Answer (score 1):

here first you need to create html string and ajax response I can assume as array so forEach loop will concatenate htmlString with options string and then remaining HTML will be concate.

So you can use your code like this:

```
    $(".creaDetFact").empty();
    $(".bvp").empty();
    var rfFac = $("#rfFac").val();
    var vTDF = "Pago de Factura";
    var datos = new FormData();
    datos.append("rdffac",rfFac);
    document.getElementById("TDF").innerHTML = vTDF;
    let htmlString = '<form role="form" method="post" autocomplete="off">'+
                        '<div class="form-group">'+
                          '<div class="col-xs-6" style="padding-right: 0px;">'+
                            '<div class="input-group">'+
                              '<select class="form-control input-lg" type="number" name="creaCate" id="creaCate" required>'+
                                '<option value="">Seleccione Categoría</option>';

    $.ajax({
      url: "ajax/ventas.ajax.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: datos,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (dataset){
        dataset.forEach((item, index) => {
          htmlString += '<option value=' + item.mp_pago + '>' + item.mp_descripcion + '</option>';
        });   
        
        htmlString += '</select>'+
                      '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-xs-6" style="padding-left: 0px;">'+
                      '<div class="input-group">'+
                        '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="rfTsc" name="rfTsc" required>'+
                        '<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>'+
                      '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                  '</div>'+
                  '<button type="button" style="margin-right: 40px" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Guardar</button>'+
                '</form>';

        $(".creaDetFact").append(htmlString);
      }      
    })
```

Comment: I'd kept pressing on the problem and arrived at a solution much quite like yours but, now I've found that the section generated on the page, is not responsive to events eg. 
``` $(".creaCate").change(function(){...}) ``` does nothing with input changes

Comment: I've read that have to use Ajax, but shall require some extra nights till I figure out how...